# Good library to load images of different formats

Tags: c#, image-processing, imaging

Hi Iam developing an image viewer application just like irfan-view or acdsee which should be capable to view lots of different image file formats (not just the standard ones which can be done with System.Drawing.Image).

Iam currently using ImageMagick but it isn't very fast and seems to be unstable with some image files.

Can anyone suggest a good imaging library, ideally with a .NET wrapper already present?

Comment: ton4eg and Gregory gave already good suggestions. Why don't you use all of them (including what you already have) and test for each file type which one matches best for you. Then you can get the best out of all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about .NET wrapper but FreeImage library is rather good. As I know it is faster than imageMagick, and less buggy.

Comment: They do have a dotnet wrapper http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/documentation.html

Comment: It seems FreeImage only focuses in modern image formats. There seem to be no support for PCX, LBM, PIC. Also it cannot render PDF files which is one thing I need.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) image library that comes with the DevIL.NET wrapper.

Comment: OK, DevIL supports 40 formats, more than FreeImage, but not nearly as much as ImageMagick supports.

Comment: you asked for an alternative :)